# MySQL query, copy data from one table to target table if it doesn't exist in the target

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something that should be easy and important from performance wise, but for unknown reason without any success. I will appreciate any help or ideas what I did wrong. I must say I saw few (more than few, in the last week) articles about this subject, but I could't understand where is my mistake.

I have 2 tables, the following are create table statment:

-1-
CREATE TABLE `LOGS` (
  `SystemId` text,
  `DeviceId` text,
  `DeviceType` text,
  `EventDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LogType` text NOT NULL,
  `Value` text NOT NULL,
  `PrevValue` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

-2-
CREATE TABLE `UID_to_SN` (
  `SystemId` text,
  `UID` text NOT NULL COMMENT ''DeviceUniqueId'',
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT ''ID in the Prd DB'',
  `SN` text NOT NULL COMMENT ''Serial Number of the device'',
  KEY `idx_UID` (`UID`(36))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

in `UID_to_SN` table the columns `SystemId`  has duplicated rows, i would like to insert(copy) only one time the value from `UID_to_SN.SystemId` to `systems_id.clm_systems_id`.

I thought the following will do the job:

```
INSERT INTO systems_id (clm_systems_id)
SELECT SystemId
from UID_to_SN
where SystemId NOT in (select clm_systems_id from systems_id);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit you question and post at least CREATE statements for two tables (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>`) and your MySQL version.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Please see : [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Add more details and instead of ending with Any idea? You might get good help/answer if you share what you already tried and what is failing with error details. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If there are duplicates, use the `distinct` keyword to remove them from the select query’s result:

```
insert into systems_id (clm_systems_id)
select distinct SystemId
from UID_to_SN
where SystemId NOT in (select clm_systems_id from systems_id)
```